# Joint Significance Test with Interaction Terms: contains bad coefficient/variable names

Tags: r, linear-regression, significance

I am trying to run a joint significance test in R:

```
library(car)
data("mtcars")
mylm <- lm(mpg ~ qsec + gear + am + am:qsec + am:hp, data=mtcars)

linearHypothesis(mylm, c("am + am:qsec + am:hp"))
```

But I always end up with this error:

```
Error in constants(lhs, cnames_symb) : 
  The hypothesis "am + am:qsec + am:hp" is not well formed: contains bad coefficient/variable names.
```

What I am trying to test is whether

> am + am:qsec + am:hp = 0

I have found in the documentation how to test for all interaction terms:

```
linearHypothesis(mylm, matchCoefs(mylm, ":"), verbose=TRUE)
```

But I want to test interaction terms and level terms together. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply notice that

```
mylm$coefficients
# (Intercept)        qsec        gear          am     qsec:am       am:hp 
# -12.2376256   0.8891289   4.1170265 -19.4050359   1.5298394  -0.0316123
```

has `qsec:am` rather than `am:qsec`. Then

```
linearHypothesis(mylm, c("am + qsec:am + am:hp"))
```

does work, but this kind of ordering isn't something obvious. For instance,

```
lm(mpg ~ am:qsec + am:hp, data = mtcars)$coef
# (Intercept)     am:qsec       am:hp 
#  17.1256930   0.7542508  -0.0456892
```

Comment: Looks so easy once I see it. Thanks a lot, I couldn't figure this out in the documentation.

Comment: Right, as I meant to demonstrate, the naming indeed doesn't seem to follow a clear pattern.